# Using sortBy on multiple elements in a List of Nested Tuples in Scala

Tags: scala

Given the following data type `[((String, String), Double)]` in Scala how would I used the sortBy function to sortby the First String then the second String? There are some answers for sorting on multiple values but what about in the case below?

```
var test = 
  List((("C","c"),4.3), (("A","c"),1.4), (("C","d"),80.1))

test.sortBy(???).foreach(println)
```

Output should provide following

```
(("A","c"),1.4),  
(("C","c"),4.3),
(("C","d"),80.1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the elements within each tuple `((s1, s2), d)` are already in the order (from left to right) you want for the sorting, you can simply do this:

```
test.sortBy(identity)
// List[((String, String), Double)] = List(((A,c),1.4), ((C,d),80.1), ((D,c),4.3))
```

Or, just use `sorted`:

```
test.sorted
// List[((String, String), Double)] = List(((A,c),1.4), ((C,d),80.1), ((D,c),4.3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that sorting by a tuple where every element, from left to right is more relevant.

```
var test = List((("D","c"),4.3), (("A","c"),1.4), (("C","d"),80.1))

test.sortBy{ case ((a,b),c) => (a,b,c) }.foreach(println)
```